# Log in to google/gmail programmatically

Tags: python, twill

I am trying to log in to gmail via their web page.

I used twill to set the Email and Passwd fields, submitted it, but get the same form again.

```
from twill.commands import *
b = get_browser()
b.go("http://www.gmail.com")
f = b.get_form("1")
f["Email"] = "email@gmail"
f["Passwd"] = "passwd"
b.submit()
```

The next page has the same form again.

```
Form #1
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     GALX                     hidden    (None)       R5TkYbaTJMA 
2     continue                 hidden    (None)       https://mail.google.com/mail/ 
3     service                  hidden    (None)       mail 
4     rm                       hidden    (None)       false 
5     ltmpl                    hidden    (None)       default 
6     scc                      hidden    (None)       1 
7     ss                       hidden    (None)       1 
8     _utf8                    hidden    _utf8        ☃ 
9     bgresponse               hidden    bgresponse   js_disabled 
10    Email                    email     Email         
11    Passwd                   password  Passwd        
12 1  signIn                   submit    signIn       Sign in 
13    PersistentCookie         hidden    (None)       yes
```

Comment: I know there are APIs but I need to authenticate via the web page for my case.

Comment: Could you do show_cookies before and after?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the `ENTER` key or click on the login button.

In Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```